# create invoice from a shopping cart

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to display the output of a shopping cart to an invoice. the data are displaying but not properly. 
[image]

here's my code below

l

```html
 <table class="table table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Qty</th>
                                        <th>Item</th>
                                        <th>Subtotal</th>
                                    </tr>                                    
                                </thead>
                                
                                     <?php
   if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
             
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
     $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
     $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
     $pname=get_product_name($pid);
     if($q==0) continue;
   ?>        
                                <tbody>
                                         
       // Display
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $q?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $pname?></td>
                                        <td>$ <?php echo get_price($pid)*$q?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>                            
                        </div><!-- /.col -->
                    </div><!-- /.row -->

  <?php     
    }
   ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- accepted payments column --><!-- /.col -->
                        
                        <div class="col-xs-6" align="right">
                            <p class="lead">&nbsp;</p>
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Total:</th>
                                        <td> $<?php echo get_order_total()?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    
                                     <?php
            }
   else{
    echo "<tr bgColor='#FFFFFF'><td>There are no items in your shopping cart!</td>";
   }
  ?>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                      </div><!-- /.col -->
```

I want to arrange it so it can display like the first result.

> I hope it will send this time.

Comment: What are the errors? What is the expected behaviour that does not work?

Comment: as you can see in the image i added, the other product is not aligning properly

Comment: I dont see that in the image. One quick tip, first separate mark-up from the business logic. This is a horrible design and you will get a lot of unexpected issues.

Comment: @anelka Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Always write indented code. It will help you in debugging and look good.**

I tried to update the html as you required in image. Please try as below :

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Subtotal</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    if(is_array($_SESSION['cart']))
    {
        $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
        for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++)
        {
            $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
            $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
            $pname=get_product_name($pid);
            if($q==0) continue;
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $q?></td>
                <td><?php echo $pname?></td>
                <td>$ <?php echo get_price($pid)*$q?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php                   
        } 
    }
    else
    { ?>
        <tr bgColor='#FFFFFF'>
            <td>There are no items in your shopping cart!</td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php
if(is_array($_SESSION['cart']))
{ ?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6" align="right">
        <p class="lead">&nbsp;</p>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Total:</th>
                    <td>$<?php echo get_order_total()?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```